# EF6 - Update - Select/Filter items on EntityState in Context

Tags: entity-framework-6, updates, dbcontext

Here's my issue : I've created a generic method to update entities in my context that automatically add some properties (update date, update user id...).

(in the code, this is the function ModificationSet() )

My problem is that when I look for items modified in my context, I look for the state of every entity

```
    public static bool Update<U>(U dContext, int iCurrentUserId)
        where U : DbContext
    {
        using (var tx = dContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (T tItem in dContext.Set<T>())
                {
                    if (dContext.Entry(tItem).State != EntityState.Modified) continue;
                    ModificationSet(tItem, iCurrentUserId);
                }
                dContext.SaveChanges();
                tx.Commit();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                tx.Rollback();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

My issue : when I update one entity in a table of 10 000, it is looping on the 10 000 elements.

I would like to do something like that :

```
foreach (T tItem in dContext.Set<T>().Where(z => dContext.Entry(z).State == EntityState.Modified))
```

But LinQ is not OK with the filter.

Is there a way to no loop on every entity and get only the ones with the EntityState Modified ?

Thanks for any information,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine helps me and find what I think is the better solution :

```
foreach (T tItem in dContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(z => z.State == EntityState.Modified).Select(z => z.Entity))
```

Thanks to him :)